# MS Windows: running several commands in parallel

Tags: batch-file, groovy, parallel-processing, batch-processing

When running the following command in Windows 7...

```
FOR /L %%N IN (1,1,20) DO start /B groovy -cp selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar script.groovy box%%N
```

... I expected 20 groovy processes will be started (almost) simultaneously. Instead, I'm having no more than 5 processes operating at the same time. When one script ends and the whole number of running scripts becomes 4, than one more script is starting. As far as I understand, it's gonna be some kind of limitation for the "start" command in Windows.

**Question**: any options to run 20 scripts simultaneously? 20 is not a magic number here. I just want to get rid of 5 scripts limitation introducing by the "start" command.

A note for those familiar with selenium: for a couple of reasons, I don't want to use Selenium Grid to run scripts simultaneously on several nodes.

Thanks,
Racoon

Comment: There is no limitation in the "start" command that I am aware of. I wrote a simple C# app that would sleep for (5+n) seconds (where n is 1->20 as per your example) to test. All 20 instances were running simultaneously. Hope that helps - I'll post the code as an answer if you like, but it's really nothing special!

Comment: RB, thanks, your code would be appreciated. I still don't understand why I'm facing this limitation for the "start" command though, but your code could give me some clue...

Comment: Code posted, including the output from my machine (Windows 8.1 VM running on Parallels on Mac OSX for what it's worth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Batch code simply executes a program called WaitApp.exe, passing in a number each time.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%N IN (1,1,20) DO start "Waiting:%%N" /B WaitApp.exe %%N
@ECHO ON
```

C# code for WaitApp.exe

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Started #" + args[0]);
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5 + id));
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped #" + args[0]);
    }
}
```

As you can see from the following output, all 20 instances were being executed simultaneously.

```
Started #6
Started #3
Started #10
Started #11
Started #12
Started #18
Started #7
Started #8
Started #20
Started #4
Started #13
Started #19
Started #14
Started #1
Started #15
Started #9
Started #16
Started #17
Stopped #1
Stopped #2
Stopped #3
Stopped #4
Stopped #5
Stopped #6
Stopped #7
Stopped #8
Stopped #9
Stopped #10
Stopped #11
Stopped #12
Stopped #13
Stopped #14
Stopped #15
Stopped #16
Stopped #17
Stopped #18
Stopped #19
Stopped #20
```